# Pandas : Merge values to same column (replace missing values by merging dataframes)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Consider the following `dataframes`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Letters':('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
    'Position':(1,np.nan,3,4,np.nan,6)
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Letters':('B','E'),
    'Position':(2,5)
})
```

I want to replace the missing values in `df1` with their corresponding value in `df2`.  However, when I merge as follows:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Letters',how='left')
```

I end up with 2 `Position` columns as follows:

[image]

when I want:

[image]

How can I achieve this?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Personally, I think anyone with this question won't be able to find the 'duplicate' question "Error when using update between two tables joined by a code" as the title is not very descriptive.

Comment: I also think my stylised question is easier for someone new to follow than the question in "Error when using update between two tables joined by a code" which is a bit convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method to get the expected result :

```py
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Letters', how='left', suffixes=('','_Temp'))
df['Position'] = df['Position'].fillna(df['Position_Temp'])
df = df.drop(df.filter(regex='_Temp').columns, axis=1)
```

To push the answer further and avoid the `merge`, we can start to set the index for the two `DataFrames` like so :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Letters':('A','B','C','D','E','F'),
    'Position':(1,np.nan,3,4,np.nan,6)})
df1 = df1.set_index('Letters')

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Letters':('B','E'),
    'Position':(2,5)
})
df2 = df2.set_index('Letters')
```

And then use the [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method to get the expected result :

```py
df1.combine_first(df2).reset_index()
```

Output :

```
    Letters Position
0   A       1.0
1   B       2.0
2   C       3.0
3   D       4.0
4   E       5.0
5   F       6.0
```

Comment: Any way to get the desired result within the merging combining step?  This will mean I need to (1) merge; (2) fillna; (3) delete Position_x and Position_y.  Was hoping for 1 step which might be cleaner...

Comment: Hi @brb ! Thanks for accepting the answer :) ! I pushed it further to answer your comment. We can avoid the `merge` by using the index of both Dataframe. Hope it helps :) ! Have a good day my friend.

Comment: Thank you.  Appreciated.  I think this will be helpful to people that follow.  Thanks for your help.